# Android layout equivalent of HTML HR tag?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any Android layout equivalent for HTML `<HR />` tag?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use next trick:

```
<View 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="2dp"       
   android:background="#ffffff"/>
```

This will draw horizontal line of white color with 2dp in height.

Comment: the layout_width value "fill_parent" is deprecated since api level 8. Use "match_parent" instead. Thanks for the answer:-)

Answer (score 6):

Use `View` tag as:

```
<View 
android:layout_height="1dp" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:background="@#000000"/>
```

it will give you a line.

update: Using dp in layout_height and no px

Comment: it should be 1dp. Otherwise it will not scale on different resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

### Thanks, just used your idea, but had to do it programatically, adding as a view like so:

```
    View horizontalRule = new View(getApplicationContext());
    horizontalRule.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    ));
    horizontalRule.setMinimumHeight(2);
    horizontalRule.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    ((LinearLayout)linearLayout).addView(horizontalRule);
```

Comment: `setContentView((LinearLayout)linearLayout).addView(horizontalRule);`
just adding more spice to your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In html is horizontal line a tag hr. In Android source code you can use a View as xml example bellow.

```
< View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="4dip"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:paddingBottom="10dip"
/>
```

This works for you...

Answer (score -1):

In android no xml tag for that. The alternative for that is create a textview with layout height as 1 dip and background with black color. So that you will get 1 horizontal line

Comment: Kindly write your suggestions in comment section only. Thanks :)